# React : using props outside of render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I use the semantic tab components of the user interface in my project. I want to render dynamically tabs with tab items. But, I can’t call the props dialog outside the component to go through all the elements of the object and pass a property to Tab.Pane that will display the contents

```
const panes = dialogs.map((d, index) => ({
    menuItem:
        <Menu.Item key={index}>
            <AppMessageUserList {...d} />
        </Menu.Item>,
    render: () =>
        <Tab.Pane>
            <AppMessageItems  {...d} />
        </Tab.Pane>
}));
```

**Render:**

```
const AppMessages = () => {

    return (
        <Container>
            <Tab
                menu={{fluid: true, vertical: true}}
                menuPosition='left'
                panes={panes}
            />
        </Container>
    );
};
```

**Data from redux**

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        dialogs: state.dialogs,
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try `useSelector()` from `react-redux`

Comment: @atadnmz no, i didn't use, can you help, how i can quickly fix this with useSelector() ?